# How can we implement snapchat like filters in flutter using ArCore

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to build an augmented reality application using flutter and  i came to know that there are two libraries available for  flutter
[arcore_flutter_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin) for **Android** and [arkit_flutter_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/arkit_plugin)  for **IOS** can anybody suggest me how can i implement snapchat like camera filters and record that video.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the correct approach to get a working face-filter project.

As far as I know - I am working on a similar project - the best choice as of now is [DeepAR](https://www.deepar.ai), which may enable you to work with some sort of Snapchat like face-filter.